# Firebase firestore endpoint

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, retrofit2

I want to retrive document's name & data from Firestore using the endpoint 
 with Reftrofit2 
I have got the base url for firebase

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/$PROJECT_ID/databases/
```

but I didnt know what is the end point to get document's name in specific collection
and the end point to get document 's data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls) for the Cloud Firestore REST API, you should do as follows:

> To create a path to a document with the ID `LA` in the collection `cities`
>   under the project `YOUR_PROJECT_ID` you would use the following
>   structure.
>
> `/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA`
>
> To interact with this path, combine it with the base API URL.
>
> `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA`